# Please check my example of a free abelian group that has the same rank as its subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, free-abelian-group

Is the following correct?

The infinite group of integers $\Bbb Z$ under the operation of addition is a free abelian group with generator $1$. The subgroup $2\Bbb Z$ is also cyclic (with generator $2$) and thus the same rank as $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: This is right.  For an example with rank greater than $1$ the rank will need to be infinite.

Comment: @trivial $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a free abelian group of rank $2$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField right I mis-thought.  $2\Bbb Z×2\Bbb Z$ is free abelian of rank $2$.  I had dropped the word abelian.

Comment: This is a somewhat subtle point.   Whether we want free, and abelian,  or  "free abelian".

Comment: Actually I think $F_2$ does have a proper subgroup of rank $2$.  So my first comment was still off.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: Hey all thanks for your comments. Just to add it is fair to say $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ even though they are both infinite?

Comment: Yes, they are isomorphic but it is a proper subgroup.  $\Bbb Z$ has infinitely many isomorphic subgroups.   A generalization of this is, in a sense, free groups.